# mariadb SQL query showing summary lines with aggregated values

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to write a SQL query in MariaDB to print a report with in between summary lines with aggregated values.

e.g. the data in the EMP table is:

```
EmpName    ROLE         SALARY
A          Manager      10000
B          operator      8000
C          operator      8500
D          GM           20000
E          Manager       9000
```

I need an output like:

```
ROLE       EmpName    SALARY
Manager    A          10000
           E           9000
TOTAL                 19000
----------------------------
GM         D          20000
TOTAL                 20000 
----------------------------
operator   B           8000
           C           8500
TOTAL                 16500
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This sort of operation is usually undertaken by the presentation layer of the application.

Comment: Need to write a sql only. e.g in Oracle there is "compute" command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use WITH ROLLUP modifier, for example -

```
SELECT
  role, empname, SUM(salary)
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  role, empname WITH ROLLUP;
```

Output:

```
GM        D       20000
GM        (null)  20000
Manager   A       10000
Manager   E       9000
Manager   (null)  19000
operator  B       8000
operator  C       8500
operator  (null)  16500
(null)    (null)  55500
```

All NULL values for grouped columns are total values. The last row is grand total value for all salaries.

[GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifiers documentation.

Comment: Thanks this works and I guess using "WITH ROLLUP" is the best way to write this kind of queries in MariaDB

Answer (score 2):

The following query can produce an output similar to the one you want:

```
SELECT IF(type = 1, ROLE, 'TOTAL'), SALARY
FROM (
   SELECT ROLE, SALARY, 1 AS type
   FROM mytable

   UNION ALL

   SELECT ROLE, SUM(SALARY) AS TotalSalary, 2 AS type
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY ROLE) AS t
ORDER BY ROLE, type
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c2ce/2)